# Insert delimiter after every other token/value following key in string

Tags: java

I have a String like this:

```
String content = "key1: hello key2: bye key3: key4: adios";
```

What I want to be able to do is manipulate the String in a way where the value can become:

```
key1: hello | key2: bye | key3: | key:4 adios
```

I am retrieving this content from a file so I dont have to neccesairly manipulate an Object of type String. It can be anything. 
Note: some of the values following the key can be empty a shown in the example.

My end goal is to populate a map with from this file. I am going to use `com.google.common.base.Splitter;`
to enable this to happen. With the ":" being the key-value seperator and the "|" being the split between each key value pair.

One more thing the txt file structure is unpredictable. It may not be a simple as

```
key1: hello
key2: bye
key3: 
key4: adios
```

It may be something like

```
key1: hello  key2: hello
key3: 
key4: adios
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a find and replacement using the following pattern:

```
([^:]+:\s+\w+)\s+
```

This captures each colon separated key value pair, and we replace with this captured quantity followed by a pipe.  Note that we don't need to worry about the edge case of the last key value pair, because it does not need to be followed by a pipe.

```
String content = "key1: hello key2: bye key3: key4: adios";
String output = content.replaceAll("([^:]+:\\s+\\w+)\\s+", "$1 | ");
System.out.println(output);

key1: hello | key2: bye | key3: key4: adios
```

### Demo

Comment: Thanks. That is really helpful. Do you have any sources where I can learn more about RegEx? As I don't really understand how the values in the .replaceAll really work. Thanks again

Comment: I really like this regex site: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html ... beyond this, just try to get some practice.  Stack Overflow is a great place to do that.